# Can Delphi VCL project be compiled to a browser plugin?

Tags: delphi, firefox, plugins, browser, vcl

I have a Delphi VCL application which I'm using to show some pictures and I would like to know if there is any possibility to transform it into a browser plugin (like firefox, google chrome etc ) in order to load it remotely, like a java applet.

Comment: IIRC, a few years ago, I've created a small proof of concept which was actually displaying a Delphi form with a button(on click showed a message using ShowMessage) within webpage, while I can't remember the whole steps, I remember that it was fairly easy.

Comment: While `ActiveX` is mostly dead, because it was and is a trust/security nightmare, there exist no other sane alternatives that work in current browsers.  Delphi is a native language not a web applet language. Some day, perhaps Delphi will support NaCL and NaCL will be supported in most or all browsers, but even then, you'd only be able to function on a PC on Windows.

Comment: If your question is "can I directly compile a Delphi VCL application so it's a cross-browser compatible plugin?", the answer is no. The closest thing to it would be to create an ActiveForm (an ActiveX library containing an ActiveForm that is compatible with Internet Explorer *if* IE is configured to allow ActiveX controls).

Comment: Using [DelphiWebScript](http://delphitools.info/dwscript/) and [Smart Mobile Studio](http://op4js.com/) it is possible to create a javascript html5 application with object pascal (delphi style). This could be run in chrome,safari,firefox etc. I'm not saying you could use the VCL straight off, but there is a similar component layer being introduced in Smart Mobile Studio.

Comment: @LURD VCL doesn't run on Javascript, it runs on win32

Comment: Okay I thought of a really long shot.   Oxygene/Prism (Delphi-like language for .net runtime) has been ported to run on the JVM. You could write a delphi-like app using delphi-like syntax but using whatever Java UI library (Swing, or other) that you choose, and make a web "applet". But I bet it would be easier, and more well documented to just write it IN JAVA. :-)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I didn't say VCL was involved. The Smart Mobile Studio offers a RAD environment with components like Delphi VCL, still using Delphi syntax but when compiled produces javascript.

Comment: @LURD question is specifically about VCL

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, well that could be so, but the word `transform` caught my attention. Anyway that's why it was a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

for all of them the answer is NO. even for IE it is sometimes difficult...VCL applications means win32/64 development in general, browsers are more 'related' to web development. you can reconsider and try to resolve this by using an already existing platform which can be easily integrated into web browsers like [Shockwave](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Shockwave) (yeah, I don't like to give links to wikipedia...) or another similar tool.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [VirtualUI](https://www.cybelesoft.com/thinfinity/virtualui/requirements/) from CybeleSoft to run your Windows app in a browser. You still need to set up your backend server with database etc, and make sure that some operations are blocked - you don't want someone to browse through your server files ;-)

Answer (score 0):

There are options:

- ActiveX plugin (you might need to enable ActiveX support in browser or use a special plugin to enable it)
- NPAPI plugin (will be deprecated in Chrome in late 2014). See question: [How to embed Delphi VCL form into HTML page using NPAPI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22905660/how-to-embed-delphi-vcl-form-into-html-page-using-npapi)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the samples on **[Raudus](http://www.raudus.com/blog)**. It might be what you are looking for. It will be interesting for you to read **[this](http://raudus.wikispaces.com/Components+-+RaVCL)** about VCL compatible component set for the web.